# how to use string variable as column name in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, variables

I am not sure that such a thing is possible. But I want to use a variable as column name.

Below is the code I have to use

```
cartall.CartItems = cartdatas.Select(a => new Models.DTO.CartDTO.CartVM()
{
    VariationId = a.VariationId,
    ColorName = a.ColorName,
    StockInfo = rpstock.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == a.VariationId).Yellow
}).ToList();
```

But I want to use it like below.

The code I want to use:

```
cartall.CartItems = cartdatas.Select(a => new Models.DTO.CartDTO.CartVM()
{
    VariationId = a.VariationId,
    ColorName = a.ColorName,
    StockInfo = rpstock.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == a.VariationId).(a.ColorName)
}).ToList();
```

My Stock.cs

```
public class Stock:Base.BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Yellow { get; set; }
    public int? Red { get; set; }
    public int? White { get; set; }

    public virtual VariationEntity.Variation Variation { get; set; }
}
```

My Variation.cs

```
public class Variation : Base.BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OwnerProductID { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public short? Height { get; set; }
    public short? Width { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public string Delivery { get; set; }
    public int? OrderLimit { get; set; }

    public virtual StockEntity.Stock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

I have 1 to 1 relationship between stock.cs and variation.cs

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
 StockInfo = rpstock.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == a.VariationId && x.ColorName == a.ColorName)
```

Comment: this will not work. Because "ColorName" not a column. I defined colors as columns.

Comment: Then I guess I'd need more code to see how your datatypes are laid out.

Comment: With your update it is clear, that what you want is not possible inline. You will need a `switch`-statement for yellow, red and white around the `cartdata.Select`-statement and duplicate the code for each color. This is because your code internally does not know about yellow, red and white. They are just member names, as far as the code is concerned.

Comment: thanks Bob, I decided to change the structure of the stock table. This will be difficult but will be more useful in the long run. I will create a color table, and in the stock table there will be color name, quantity columns. Then I can easily access everything

Comment: Indeed, this will be more generic. Glad you identified the design problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a `Method` which will take a `list` and a `Column Name` then return `value` of the column. Please check this.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class Stock
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Yellow { get; set; }
        public int? Red { get; set; }
        public int? White { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Stock> list = new List<Stock>();
        list.Add(new Stock(){Id=1, Yellow = 50, Red = 0, White = 205});
        list.Add(new Stock(){Id=2, Yellow = 20, Red = 200, White = 35});
        list.Add(new Stock(){Id=3, Yellow = 0, Red = 100, White = 155});

        string ColumnName = "Yellow";

        var Test1 = GetColumnValue(list.Where(m=>m.Id == 1).ToList(), ColumnName);
        var Test2 = GetColumnValue(list.Where(m=>m.Id == 2).ToList(), ColumnName);
        var Test3 = GetColumnValue(list.Where(m=>m.Id == 3).ToList(), ColumnName);

        Console.WriteLine(Test1);
        Console.WriteLine(Test2);
        Console.WriteLine(Test3);
    }

    public static object GetColumnValue(List<Stock> items, string columnName)
    {
        var values = items.Select(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(x)).FirstOrDefault();
        return values;
    }
}
```

You have to use the method `GetColumnValue` in your code like this:

```
cartall.CartItems = cartdatas.Select(a => new Models.DTO.CartDTO.CartVM()
{
    VariationId = a.VariationId,
    ColorName = a.ColorName,
    StockInfo = GetColumnValue(rpstock.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == a.VariationId).ToList(), a.ColorName)
}).ToList();
```

You can run this solution in [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zWDOpW).

Comment: imho, you miss the tag `entity-framework`. Your code runs fine for linq to object, but not for linq to entity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked fine but I will change structure of table, it will be more useful.